# Variable content of Open Graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, metadata, meta-tags

I have a website where users can make a post, if they want to sell a book.
I would like to be able to use the contents of the post as values ​​in "og:title" and "og:image" so the user can make a "Share on Facebook" post with their own image and book title.
Is that possible?

Comment: If you provide an individual, unique URL for that post, which returns the meta data when requested … yes.

Comment: Can you already show image and title on the regular page? Now also use that to create those og elements

Comment: CBroe: Is it enough to include parameters in the url (link to the page) to make it unique?
Hans Kesting: The post appear to the user when created, so yes. But I doesn't know how to use them with open graph meta. Have tried and read a lot without success.